# Is there a way to stop htaccess from adding index.php to the URL?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, .htaccess

I have been on this case for a while and I kind of figured things out the way I wanted it. However, I have this issue with my solution.

The initial problem was to make my htaccess redirect all requests to HTTPS and www prepended to the URL excluding requests starting with "sitename/api/". My solution works perfectly at the moment only but the requests coming from an HTTP url redirects to HTTPS removing any trailing path and replacing it with "index.php".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]



   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


   #Pages Redirect
   Redirect /page/faqs https://www.sitename.com/faqs
   Redirect /page/about https://www.sitename.com/about

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   SetEnv TZ Africa/Lagos
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

<Files .env>
   order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Files>


<IfModule php5_module>
  php_flag asp_tags Off
  php_flag display_errors Off
  php_value max_execution_time 960
  php_value max_input_time 1920
  php_value max_input_vars 16000
  php_value memory_limit 16384M
  php_value post_max_size 384M
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2880
  php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
  php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
 AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I expect that when the following URL is typed:
`URL:  http://sitename.com/rovers`

It should produce the following result:
`URL:  https://www.sitename.com/rovers`

But the current result is as follows:
`URL:  https://www.sitename.com/index.php`

Comment: Note the "Handle Front Controller" section. If the "REQUEST_FILENAME" is not an existing directory or file, it will redirect to `index.php`. Does `/rovers` exist? If not, then that would be why the redirect is occurring. If so, what happens if you visit `/rovers/` instead of `/rovers` (i.e. you add a `/` to the end)?

Comment: Hi @B.Fleming! To answer your questions,

1.  ```/rovers``` exists
2.  ```/rovers/``` does the exact same thing

Thanks in advance